# asp.net c# multiple PlaceHolders on page with multiple dynamic buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im creating dynamic buttons and adding unique ones to 2 different placeholders.  The click event is added correctly to each button but the buttons click event is not firing on the 2nd placeholder.  If i change the buttons to be just add to the 1 placeholder they all fire correctly.  I can alter things around to get round this but im curious as to why the 2nd placeholder is an issue.  Code below:

code behind:

```
                //Create Colour Button
                RadButton buttonColour = new RadButton();
                buttonColour.EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet = false;
                buttonColour.EnableEmbeddedSkins = false;
                buttonColour.CssClass = "VariationButtonsColour";
                buttonColour.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                buttonColour.Height = new Unit(45);
                buttonColour.Click += new EventHandler(ColourClick);
                buttonColour.Text = Colour;
                buttonColour.ButtonType = RadButtonType.SkinnedButton;
                buttonColour.ID = dr["Colour"].ToString() ;
                buttonColour.PressedCssClass = "VariationButtonsColourActive";

                foreach (Control ctrl in phColourButtons.Controls)
                {
                    if (ctrl is RadButton)
                    {
                        RadButton button = (RadButton)ctrl;
                        if (buttonColour.ID == button.ID)
                        {
                            ColourExists = ColourExists + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (ColourExists == 0)
                {
                    phColourButtons.Controls.Add(buttonColour);
                    Label spacer = new Label();
                    spacer.Width = new Unit(15);
                    spacer.Text = "&nbsp;&nbsp;";

                    phColourButtons.Controls.Add(spacer);
                }


                //Create Size Button
                RadButton buttonSize = new RadButton();
                buttonSize.EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet = false;
                buttonSize.EnableEmbeddedSkins = false;
                buttonSize.CssClass = "VariationButtonsSize";
                buttonSize.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                buttonSize.Height = new Unit(45);
                buttonSize.Click += new EventHandler(SizeClick);
                buttonSize.Text = Size;
                buttonSize.ButtonType = RadButtonType.SkinnedButton;
                buttonSize.ID = dr["Size"].ToString();
                buttonSize.PressedCssClass = "VariationButtonsSizeActive";


                foreach (Control ctrl in phSizeButtons.Controls)
                {
                    if (ctrl is RadButton)
                    {
                        RadButton button = (RadButton)ctrl;
                        if (buttonSize.ID == button.ID)
                        {
                            SizeExists = SizeExists + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (SizeExists == 0)
                {
                    phSizeButtons.Controls.Add(buttonSize);
                    Label spacer = new Label();
                    spacer.Width = new Unit(15);
                    spacer.Text = "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    phSizeButtons.Controls.Add(spacer);
                }
```

If someone could explain why the 2nd placeholder is not working that would be great.

Comment: Other than the lack of reuse everything looks ok in what you have posted. Two things that could be the cause would be a possible overlap in the div of the first container that is over the second button (inspect the element in the broswer dev tools) or something in your second event handler (not shown) is wrong.

Comment: I have checked the source and even added a border to all divs to try and see if that shows anything up.  But still nothing.  Like mentioned the buttons fire if i add them to the 1st placeholder.  Just not when added to the 2nd.  Yeah my reuse of code is apawling i know. lol